# Angular 2/4 - Extending a third party module

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

**Background**
We are building a supposedly large web app in Angular 4. For obvious reasons, we are using third-party components to bring in advanced features like data grids and several other controls. I am using DevExtreme controls however this question can be applied to any other third party controls provider.

**Problem Statement**
How do we safe guard against future scenarios, where we have used a third party component in several locations but want to now add a new functionality to the underlying component itself. Let us say, I use a third party button control. We click the button and it uses (onClick) to call a method in the component it has been used in. All is good so far. What if we decide in future, that each button clicked shall also capture click frequency information so that a heat map can be generated for how a certain web page is being used by the clients. This is a hypothetical scenario just for the purpose of this problem statement.

How can we ensure that these kind of modifications can be made in one place instead of say the 300 locations where the button has been used?

**How would this be done in Java/C#**
We would simply create our own class called MySuperButton and *inherit* it from the third party supplies button class. We could then override certain base methods and write our own extended logic implementation. Then we would use this MySuperButton object throughout the app instead of directly using the third party supplier button.

**Known Solution with its known limitation**
Composition is the technique described everywhere to achieve the above. What that means is we create our own MySuperButtonComponent and create a third party button instance inside of it. Then we write our own code to map say an onClick handler on our MySuperButton to its underlying third party button instance.
The limitation with this method is, that its Composition vs Inheritance.

**Why does inheritance not work the best**
Inheritance would have solved this problem in a far more clean manner, however I can't inherit templates, styles, decorators etc. in Angular 2/4. This leads to a lot of re-write.

I hope this question makes sense, and I am sure a lot of people are struggling with the very same problem. I wasn't sure if a better way of solving this has come around since then.